# Golang parse HTML, extract all content with <body> </body> tags

Tags: html, go

I am needing to return all of the content within the body tags of an HTML document, including any subsequent HTML tags, etc. I'm curious to know what the best way to go about this is. I had a working solution with the Gokogiri package, however I am trying to stay away from any packages that depend on C libraries. Is there a way to accomplish this with the go standard library? or with a package that is 100% Go?

Since posting my original question I have attempted to use the following packages that have yielded no resolution. (Neither of which seem to return subsequent children or nested tags from inside the body. For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Title of the document
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        body content 
        <p>more content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

will return body content, ignoring the subsequent `<p>` tags and the text they wrap):

- pkg/encoding/xml/ (standard library xml package)
- golang.org/x/net/html

The overall goal would be to obtain a string or content that would look like:

```html
<body>
    body content 
    <p>more content</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the standard xml package can do that. and if not, try goquery https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I attempted to used the standard XML package, however I have not been able to get it to read child/nested tags within the body as a string. For example: <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Title of the document</title></head><body>body content <p>more content</p></body></html> will return body content, ignoring the subsequent <p> tags and the text they wrap.

Comment: You could try the [`golang.org/x/net/html`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html/) package.

Comment: @DaveC I have been trying this as well. For the life of me I cannot get it to return nested tags the way in which I'm expecting. Its the same issue in my reply to Not_a_Golfer

Comment: @user2737876 You should probably [edit] the question to include the information in your first comment.

Comment: @DaveC I had not tried these before posting my original issue. I had tried been trying the package as you left your comment. Will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 68):

This can be solved by recursively finding the body node, using the html package, and subsequently render the html, starting from that node.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
    "io"
    "strings"
)

func Body(doc *html.Node) (*html.Node, error) {
    var body *html.Node
    var crawler func(*html.Node)
    crawler = func(node *html.Node) {
        if node.Type == html.ElementNode && node.Data == "body" {
            body = node
            return
        }
        for child := node.FirstChild; child != nil; child = child.NextSibling {
            crawler(child)
        }
    }
    crawler(doc)
    if body != nil {
        return body, nil
    }
    return nil, errors.New("Missing <body> in the node tree")
}

func renderNode(n *html.Node) string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    w := io.Writer(&buf)
    html.Render(w, n)
    return buf.String()
}

func main() {
    doc, _ := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(htm))
    bn, err := Body(doc)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    body := renderNode(bn)
    fmt.Println(body)
}

const htm = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    body content
    <p>more content</p>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: I think we can add `return` after `b = n` in closure body to prevent unnecessary work

Comment: You may need to `go get golang.org/x/net/html` beforehand.

Comment: Doesn't this return the last body the html content has? As i see it, the body will be overwritten in the recursive call. The content of "all body tags" (as asked) is never added up. Its just the content of the last body the crawler sees. The return statement in the crawler function only avoids nested body tags.

Answer (score 11):

It can be done using the standard `encoding/xml` package. But it's a bit cumbersome. And one caveat in this example is that it will not include the enclosing body tag, but it will contain all of it's children.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type html struct {
    Body body `xml:"body"`
}
type body struct {
    Content string `xml:",innerxml"`
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Title of the document
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        body content 
        <p>more content</p>
    </body>
</html>`)

    h := html{}
    err := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBuffer(b)).Decode(&h)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(h.Body.Content)
}
```

Runnable example:
http://play.golang.org/p/ZH5iKyjRQp

Answer (score 10):

Since you didn't show the source code of your attempt with the html package, I'll have to guess what you were doing, but I suspect you were using the tokenizer rather than the parser. Here is a program that uses the parser and does what you were looking for:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/andybalholm/cascadia"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader(`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Title of the document
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        body content 
        <p>more content</p>
    </body>
</html>`)
    doc, err := html.Parse(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    body := cascadia.MustCompile("body").MatchFirst(doc)
    html.Render(os.Stdout, body)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also do this purely with strings:

```
func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader(`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Title of the document
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        body content
        <p>more content</p>
    </body>
</html>
`)
    str := NewSkipTillReader(r, []byte("<body>"))
    rtr := NewReadTillReader(str, []byte("</body>"))
    bs, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rtr)
    fmt.Println(string(bs), err)
}
```

The definitions for `SkipTillReader` and `ReadTillReader` are here: https://play.golang.org/p/6THLhRgLOa. (But basically skip until you see the delimiter and then read until you see the delimiter)

This won't work for case insensitivity (though that wouldn't be hard to change).

Comment: That's very interesting solution, except that under the hood it uses `bufio`. This is not entirely good at causing additional memory allocation. Do you know any similar solution, but without the flaw above?

Comment: Then you try to parse the body out of this perfectly valid HTML and fail miserably: `<html><head><!-- <body>haha</body> --></head><body></body></html>`

Answer (score -1):

I have written my Golang HTML DOM parser with pure Golang and no dependency used in it.
This project is still under development. But now it is usable, and I will develop it in the future.

Project link: https://github.com/pejman-hkh/gdp/

Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/ksyPWPcDq2J

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/pejman-hkh/gdp/gdp"
)

func main() {
    document := gdp.Default(`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                Title of the document
            </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            body content 
            <p>more content</p>
        </body>
    </html>`)

    body := document.Find("body").Eq(0)
    fmt.Print(body.OuterHtml())
}
```