# How to get inner HTML, or just text, of a tag?

Tags: html, go

How do we get the value of anchor text per the example below? Here is my go code. I can get the value of `href` and `title` using `html.ElementNode`. I need to get the value of text using only `golang.org/x/net/html`, with no other libraries.

Example: From `<a href="https:xyz.com">Text XYZ</a>`, I want to get "Text XYZ".

```
// html.ElementNode works for getting href and title value but no text value with TextNode. 
if n.Type == html.TextNode && n.Data == "a" {
    for _, a := range n.Attr {
        if a.Key == "href" {
            text = a.Val
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the HTML:

```html
<a href="http://example.com/1">Go to <b>example</b> 1</a>
<p>Some para text</p>
<a href="http://example.com/2">Go to <b>example</b> 2</a>
```

Do you expect just the text?

```
Go to example 1
Go to example 2
```

Do you expect the inner HTML?

```html
Go to <b>example</b>example 1
Go to <b>example</b>example 2
```

Or, do you expect something else?

The following program gives either just the text or the inner HTML.  Every time it finds an anchor node, it saves that node, then continues down that node’s tree.  As it encounters other nodes it checks against the saved node and either appends the text of TextNodes or renders the node's HTML to a buffer. Finally, after traversing all the children and re-encountering the saved anchor node, it prints the text string and the HTML buffer, resets both vars, then nils the anchor node.

I got the idea of using a buffer and html.Render, and saving a particular node, from [Golang parse HTML, extract all content with   tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38855264/246801).

The following is also in [the Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/5iOPLlaGvuz):

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
    s := `
    <a href="http://example.com/1">Go to <b>example</b> 1</a>
    <p>Some para text</p>
    <a href="http://example.com/2">Go to <b>example</b> 2</a>
    `

    doc, _ := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))

    var nAnchor *html.Node
    var sTxt string
    var bufInnerHtml bytes.Buffer

    w := io.Writer(&bufInnerHtml)

    var f func(*html.Node)
    f = func(n *html.Node) {
        if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
            nAnchor = n
        }

        if nAnchor != nil {
            if n != nAnchor { // don't write the a tag and its attributes
                html.Render(w, n)
            }
            if n.Type == html.TextNode {
                sTxt += n.Data
            }
        }

        for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
            f(c)
        }

        if n == nAnchor {
            fmt.Println("Text:", sTxt)
            fmt.Println("InnerHTML:", bufInnerHtml.String())
            sTxt = ""
            bufInnerHtml.Reset()
            nAnchor = nil
        }
    }
    f(doc)
}
```

```
Text: Go to example 1
InnerHTML: Go to <b>example</b>example 1
Text: Go to example 2
InnerHTML: Go to <b>example</b>example 2
```

Comment: This code above worked great. I wanted the text only. One more favour to ask, what if I want to print "href" or link as well? I have seperate code for that per my code example above but I don't know how to merge them. Thanks

Comment: @MrSingh, if this answer satisfies your question, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark, at the top-left of the answer. Regarding the href data, you already have that code, you included it in your question; just add it above or below `nAnchor = n`.